# Using git and svn on the same working tree independently

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I am in a classical situation: my company system is based on svn, and probably it won't be ever change. But I like git much better because of its extended functionality, stability, flexibility and speed.

Thus I try to use git on my development machine, but I want to make it invisible for the svn-centered software development (partially human-) infrastructure.

Yes, I know there is gitsvn to bridge over the gap between git and svn. But the hard truth is that I am really not satisfied with gitsvn, and the more doc I learn, I am more and more unsatisfied.

Currently I think it were better to me to simply abandon my git project and only use svn.

I have an idea, which makes things a little bit complexer, but at least it will do exactly what I want. My idea were to simply use svn and git on the same working tree independently. I am thinking on this layout:

```
.git/
    .gitignore (<- of course .svn here)
.svn/
    .svnignore (<- of course .git will be also ignored)
dir1/
dir2/
...
```

And I entirely ignored gitsvn. I simply leaved it out from everything. Of course, .git and .svn need to be invisible for both systems.

I think, it were a hard in the sense, that I needed to keep in my brain the state of both VCS-s, but I think, I will use some type of in-house standards to do that. For example, I used mainly git, and used svn only for the commits/updates to the central repository.

I know, eclipse (and most IDE) weren't able to handle a such structure, but I think I could live with that.

Anybody did the same already? What are the experiences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working dir of Git and SVN Working Copy at the same tree is **Bad Idea (tm)** - you'll get twofold of headaches for the cost of one. Git-SVN per se is reasonable smart and hides a lot of troubles behind the scene (from my POV)

You can to think about using not just naked git-svn, but neatly tucked away in two-world clients: [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/svn-index) is one of such tools

Alternative bridge between Git and SVN is [SubGit](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html)

> SubGit was developed as an alternative to Git-Svn, so quite naturally SubGit does resolve many of the Git-Svn limitations.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try SubGit! On the double VCS I am thinking on the I will use mainly only one of them (git), and the secondary only for the simplest commit/update operations. I think it won't be so hard. But I think, subgit were also a good alternative.

Comment: I can't use subgit, especially not in a workplace environment, because it is a closed source, proprietary software with a free trial.